# Repeating an AJAX request after login

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sending some information via AJAX to a PHP-Script to get some text, which should be displayed. So far there is no problem. But if the user is logged out, the result would be `false` and a modal with a login-form is shown.

If the user gets logged in, the first information (`var data`) should be send one more time, as the first sending wasn't accepted.

```
$.ajax({ 
 url: "script.php", type: "POST", data: data, dataType: "json" 
})
.done(function( json ) {
    if (json.result === false) { 
        showModal("login"); return; 
    }
     else {
        $('#result').html(json.result);
     }
});
```

The showModal function is also connected to an ajax request, so the user is getting logged in... After that the first data should be send one more time...

```
function showModal() {
    $('body').append('<form>...'); // Show Modal with form to login
}

// With submit form, the user will be logged in
$('body').on('submit','#loginform',function(event){
$.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'username': username, 'password': password },
    dataType: "json"
})
.done(function( json ) {
    // User is now logged in
    // Now repeat first request
});
});
```

Comment: what's the code that triggered when the user get logged in?

Comment: wrap the ajax call in a separate function, and call it again when conditions fail

Comment: If you want to store the data you can store it in a `cookie` or `localStorage` and use it as a paramter for the function @RaphaelMüller suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your code inside a function. You can call a function whenever you need it:

```
var sendData = function() {
    $.ajax({ url: "script.php", type: "POST", data: data, dataType: "json" })
.done(function( json ) {
        if (json.result === false) { 
            showModal("login"); return; 
        }
        else {
            $('#result').html(json.result);
        }
    });
};

// now run sendData() when you want to trigger it
```

---

Where to call `sendData()` the second time depends on how your login (showModal) works. Find a way to catch a 'successful login' event.

---

You can pass `sendData` to the `showModal` function and call it there. This way `showModal` does not need to know anything about `data`:

```
var sendData = function() {
    $.ajax({ url: "script.php", type: "POST", data: data, dataType: "json" })
.done(function( json ) {
        if (json.result === false) {
            // The function sendData is passed as a parameter - will be called after a successful login
            showModal("login", sendData); return; 
        }
        else {
            $('#result').html(json.result);
        }
    });
};
```

Then, where showModal is defined:

```
function showModal(dialog, loginCallback) {
    $('body').append('<form>...'); // Show Modal with form to login
    // With submit form, the user will be logged in
    $('#loginform').on('submit', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'username': username, 'password': password },
            dataType: "json"
        })
        .done(function( json ) {
            // User is now logged in
            // Now repeat first request
            loginCallback();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, you should be able to run `sendData()` inside the `done` callback again.

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Just an idea for further improving: Wouldn't it be better to do the login within the same function `sendData`? I mean just to avoid the second ajax in the `showModal`. It is just a question of the parameter send with `data` - of course then everything will be done with one script i.e. script.php. But then I don't know where to put the `loginCallback` into `sendData`.

Comment: I think the login and sending data should really be separate AJAX request. If you have a bunch of functions that require a login, you want the login to be handled separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the ShowModal function to accept another argument as ajax Options. The if ajax options are defined just call them in the done.

```
function showLoginModal(ajaxOptions){
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'username': username, 'password': password },
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function( json ) {
        if(ajaxOptions!== undefined){
            $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
        }
    });
}
```

Then pass the ajaxOptions from your calling function

```
$.ajax({ 
 url: "script.php", type: "POST", data: data, dataType: "json" 
})
.done(function( json ) {
    if (json.result === false) { 
        showLoginModal(this); 
    }
     else {
        $('#result').html(json.result);
     }
});
```

Comment: So I could define a new function `sendData` as shown by Raphael and call that function in `if(ajaxOptions!== undefined){`. Right?

Comment: If you have only one function say sendData that needs this functionality then it is fine to call it inside showModal directly. But if you need same thing in many or all of you ajax calls then it will be better to pass the ajax options to showModal and use $.ajax(passedOptions) inside the if condition.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post. Because showModal just shows the modal. I bind a submit event to send the login data. So with modalShow() in the middle of the process, I don't know how to connect the data...